# Eclipse for PHP

Tags: php, eclipse, apache, wamp

I have installed WAMP and enable some extension. After that i have installed eclipse for php. now my question how can i let eclipse now that i should use apache installation and the version of php which came with WAMP.

I will be developing web apps on windows.

Comment: For what it's worth I find netbeans to be better for PHP and eclipse to be better for java. Netbeans is easy to setup compared with eclipse. Netbeans also has better autocomplete for the other languages that go along with php like css, html, javascript. That's just my 2c.

Comment: I would have switched to netbeans by now but I find the Control-(or-Command)-O (letter, not zero) feature, which lists all the current class members in a searchable dialog, indispensable. I couldn't find it in netbeans.

Comment: Netbeans has a navigator pane with classes and methods. It's not searchable though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Eclipse's preferences. In the menu on the left, navigate to PHP -> PHP Executables. Click the Add button. Under executable path, put the path to the php executable. With a new installation of WAMP, the path is `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\php.exe`. Click "Finish".

For the server component, navigate to PHP -> PHP Servers in the preferences screen. If "Default PHP Web Server" does not exist or does not point to http://localhost/, click "New" and fill it in.

Take note of the "Path Mapping" tab of each server (accessible by selecting an existing server and pressing "Edit"). This lets you map a local path in your eclipse workspace to specific sub-urls of WAMP. This is useful if you deploy apps into your WAMP installation using VirtualHosts that have separate DocumentRoots.